# Everything but the media queries work in tailwind css react project

Tags: css, reactjs, vite, tailwind-css

All the classes in my project (react + vite) work except the media queries, and I am having a hard time figuring out why. I tried manually adding all the breakpoints (with the default values) in the tailwind config file which had no effect at all.

```
function Sidebar(props) {
    return(
        <>
            <aside className="text-xl p-4">
                <h1 className="font-chivoMono ">Noteit</h1>
                <h3 className="text-xl md:text-7xl text-white sm:text-red-500 md:text-green-300 lg:text-pink-300">{props.displayName}</h3>
            </aside>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

I took all the configuration steps correctly (and I think no classes would have worked if i didn't)

I tried to run the command

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ./dist/output.css
```

thinking it might do something but honestly I am just completely clueless to why this is not working
Also, the media queries do not show up while inspecting the page.

Comment: 1. Do you see the classes in dev tools? 2. Do you see the queries in the output css file?

Comment: @Konrad Yes the classes for text size and text-white do show up on dev tools and the queries are present in the output.css file